# Generating New XML File

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I have a cakePHP based website that I did not build from scratch but understand the very basics behind. I'm trying to learn more about it and have come across a problem I'd love some help with.

The site produces an xml of all our data which is essentially a .ctp file pulling variables from our database and creating the xml - a live representation of all data on our website.

We now have an affiliate who wishes to have a separate xml file with a specified set of nodes. I can quite easily add these nodes and populate them with variables in the current xml feed and they appear as expected. However, I'm not sure how to put the data in to a separate xml file for our affiliate to access.

For instance, the php script to pull data in is a .php file but the file itself should have an .xml extension - please point me in the right direction if this is a very basic misunderstanding.

Is this a straightforward thing to do? If so, some guidance (in as layman-like terms as possible!) would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: A php file can have .xml as its file ending...

Comment: What does the URL to request the XML file look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you generate an XML-File, the important thing you should do is [return the corresponding header](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php):

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

You can also make the PHP-Script accessible by using the `.xml`-extension (so it looks like its an XML-file, not a PHP-Script). More on that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044229/i-found-a-php-script-in-a-gif-file).